# Real Time services monitoring tools

Tags: .net, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, nagios, health-monitoring

I need a **High-level** open source tool for monitoring the services.

These services should be like,

```
 1. Web Services(.Net or Java)
 2. Windows Services
 3. Scheduled Tasks
```

This will need to tell the service **up** or **down**

Is it provide any **Real time alerts**(email alert) with **Health Monitoring** ??

Please give me the clear information about the tool.

Answer (score 0):

What ever **High-Level** means, but MoSKito is probably highest level possible ;-)
http://www.moskito.org

It provides real time performance and health monitoring for Java Apps, and it has an open API that allows it to consume data from other sources, allowing it to monitor .NET Applications or anything with a syslog.

Answer (score 0):

I'll second that High-Level is not a very clear description, but I think what you're looking for is: **extensibility**.

---

Nagios (now [Naemon](http://naemon.org), founded by Andreas Ericsson) is the de facto standard for monitoring complex custom variables.  The reason for this is that the core is designed to allow checking anything via scripts.  Viz-- if you can get the data from a CLI, you can monitor it with a Nagios-based solution.

If the output you need to monitor is available in logs, there are also **free** Nagios packages. These also tend to be far easier to get started with (GUI much?) if you have no experience with Nag/Naemon.

While an application-specific monitoring tool might be great as a one-off solution, it will forever be limited by its focus.  If you want a solution that can grow, and also offer a unified view of everything without hassling to repurpose using API's, Naemon is still the the way to go.